# Split a column by separating numbers and letters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column looking like this:

```
      X      

1.6 aaa_2345

1.6 aaa_2345

Bbb 1.4t_2890

Bbb 1.4t_2891

1.2 ccc_4570
```

I would like to create a new column with only the float part i.e:

```
     X
    1.6 
    1.6 
    1.4
    1.4
    1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.findall`

```
df['X'] = df['X'].str.findall(r'([\d.]+)').str[0].astype(float)
```

Or if you are sure there is always a '.' to separate digits:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].str.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)').str[0].astype(float)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     X
0  1.6
1  1.6
2  1.4
3  1.4
4  1.2
```

Comment: @benaia. Does it answer to your question?

Comment: small edit:
```df['X'] = df['X'].str.findall(r'([\d\.]+)').apply(pd.Series)[0].astype(float)```

Comment: Much better now, super, plus1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract`:

```
df['X'].str.extract('([\d.]+)').astype(float)
```

output:

```
     0
0  1.6
1  1.6
2  1.4
3  1.4
4  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns have always the same structure, you can use `str`function to retrieve the 3 fist characters and then cast as `float`.

```
df["column"].str[0:3].astype(float)
```

If this is not the case, please give more examples.